# How do I stop re-render the child component from drawer open time?

Tags: reactjs

**DrawerSidebar.jsx**

```
 import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import { Tooltip } from '@mui/material';
import { PeopleAlt, Dashboard as DashboardIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import LockIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Lock';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import LockOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOpen';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Users from '../pages/setting/Users';
import Vendors from '../pages/vendors/VendorsList';
import Logo from '../assets/homelynks-logo.jpg';
import Subscriptions from '../pages/subscription/SubscriptionList';
import AssignmentIndIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AssignmentInd';
import LocalAtmIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalAtm';
import '../style/Header.css';
import ServerDown from '../helpers/ServerDown';
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';

export default function DrawerSideBar({
  theme,
  setOpen,
  open,
  drawerWidth,
  setDrawerWidth,
  drawerLocked,
  setDrawerLocked,
  lock,
  setLock,
}) {
  const [drawer, setDrawer] = React.useState(false);

  const DashboardComponent = useMemo(() => <Dashboard />, []);
  const UsersComponent = useMemo(() => <Users drawer={drawer} />, [drawer]);
  const VendorsComponent = useMemo(() => <Vendors drawer={drawer} />, [drawer]);
  const SubscriptionsComponent = useMemo(() => <Subscriptions />, [drawer]);
  const ServerDownComponent = useMemo(() => <ServerDown />, []);

  const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
      }),
      marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
      ...(open && {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
          easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
      }),
    })
  );

  const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  }));

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    if (drawerLocked === false) {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  };

  const handleDrawerLock = () => {
    setDrawerLocked(!drawerLocked);
    setLock(!lock);
  };

  const handleDrawerExpand = () => {
    if (drawer === false) {
      setDrawer(!drawer);
      setDrawerWidth(170);
    } else {
      setDrawer(!drawer);
      setDrawerWidth(70);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
          },
        }}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        locked={drawerLocked}
        onMouseLeave={handleDrawerClose}
      >
        <DrawerHeader className="drawer-align">
          {drawer ? (
            <img
              src={Logo}
              style={{ height: '50px', width: '100%' }}
              alt="org-img"
            />
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
          {lock ? (
            <Tooltip title="Lockopen" placement="bottom-start" arrow>
              <LockIcon
                onClick={handleDrawerLock}
                size="small"
                className="icon1"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          ) : (
            <Tooltip title="Lock" placement="bottom-start" arrow>
              <LockOpenIcon
                size="small"
                onClick={handleDrawerLock}
                className="icon2"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          )}
          <Tooltip title="Expand" placement="right" arrow>
            <ChevronLeftIcon
              onClick={handleDrawerExpand}
              size="small"
              className="icon3"
            />
          </Tooltip>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          <Link to="/dashboard" className="link">
            <Tooltip title="Dashboard" placement="right" arrow>
              <ListItem>
                <DashboardIcon
                  className="point"
                  sx={[
                    { mr: 1 },
                    (theme) => ({
                      '&:hover': { color: theme.palette.primary.dark },
                    }),
                  ]}
                />
                {
                  drawer ? <div className="margin">Dashboard</div> : <></>
                  // <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />:<></>
                }
              </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
          </Link>
          <Divider />
          <Link to="/users" className="link">
            {console.log('USERSSS')}
            <Tooltip title="Users" placement="right" arrow>
              <ListItem>
                <PeopleAlt
                  className="point"
                  sx={[
                    { mr: 1 },
                    (theme) => ({
                      '&:hover': { color: theme.palette.primary.dark },
                    }),
                  ]}
                  style={{ color: 'inherit' }}
                />
                {drawer ? <div className="margin">Users</div> : <></>}
              </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
          </Link>
          <Divider />
          <Link to="/vendors" className="link">
            <Tooltip title="Vendors" placement="right" arrow>
              <ListItem>
                <AssignmentIndIcon
                  className="point"
                  sx={[
                    { mr: 1 },
                    (theme) => ({
                      '&:hover': { color: theme.palette.primary.dark },
                    }),
                  ]}
                />
                {
                  drawer ? <div className="margin">Vendors</div> : <></>
                  // <ListItemText primary="Vendors" />:<></>
                }
              </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
          </Link>
          <Divider />
          <Link to="/subscription" className="link">
            {console.log('SUBSCRIPTION')}
            <Tooltip title="Subscription" placement="right" arrow>
              <ListItem
                sx={{
                  '&:hover': {
                    color: 'theme.palette.primary.dark !important', // Change to the desired hover color
                  },
                }}
              >
                <LocalAtmIcon
                  className="point"
                  sx={{ mr: 1 }}
                  // sx={[
                  //   { mr: 1 },
                  //   (theme) => ({
                  //     '&:hover': { color: theme.palette.primary.dark },
                  //   }),
                  // ]}
                />
                {
                  drawer ? <div className="margin">Subscription</div> : <></>
                  // <ListItemText primary="Subscription" />:<></>
                }
              </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
          </Link>
          <Divider />
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Main>
        <DrawerHeader />
        <Typography noWrap>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={DashboardComponent} />
            <Route path="/users" element={UsersComponent} />
            <Route path="/vendors" element={VendorsComponent} />
            <Route path="/subscription" element={SubscriptionsComponent} />
            <Route path="/error" element={ServerDownComponent} />
          </Routes>
        </Typography>
      </Main>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is my code in it comes from props `open` is true. then the drawer is true at that time it will automatically re-renders the child components. but i don't need to re-render the child component at that time. how do restrict re-render the child component. when i click the icon then only i need to render the child component. somebody can help me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).